# style to make a LinkButton appear as a hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, hyperlink, linkbutton

style to make a LinkButton appear as a hyperlink

inline css style=" "

thanku

Comment: What's the question ....

Comment: Umm... LinkButton **Appears** as a hyperlink by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this css command in your paragraph tag or iin the header tag.We can able to set color for the link, when it is active,visited and when the mouse is over the link.

```
A:link {color: blue;}
A:visited {color: purple;}
A:active {color: red;}
A:hover {color: red;}
```

*Text decoration*

- underline - This will underline your hyperlink text.
- overline - This will apply a line on top of your hyperlink text.
- none - This will remove the underlining normally applied to hyperlink text.

Syntax

```
text-decoration:none;
```

you can use(`underline`,`overline`)